# Missing AuthConfig.cs

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've created an ASP MVC 4 web application in Visual Studio 2012 Express. I wanted to intagrate with Facebook and started looking around for documentation and have seen references to a `AuthConfig.cs` file in the `App_Start` folder of the example project.

I looked in my project and there was no `AuthConfig.cs` in my `App_Start` folder. After some looking around I seen that I needed to use NuGet to install the *DotNetOpenAuth* package so off I went and installed it but to my surprise there still is no `AuthConfig.cs` file in my `App_Start` folder.

Has anyone had this issue or know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new project.

The Startup.CS contains following code.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(Gather.Startup))]
namespace Gather
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Just check if you have following Packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```